# UWP C# Switching frame content issues and crashes

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I've struggled with this setup for couple of days and found a somewhat solution but I think it not how it supposed to work.

Here is my xaml page setup:

```
<Page
    ...
    <SplitView IsPaneOpen="True" DisplayMode="Inline" OpenPaneLength="300">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Grid>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Edit" IsEnabled="False" Checked="Edit_Checked" Unchecked="Edit_Unchecked"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <Frame x:Name="RightFrame">

        </Frame>
    </SplitView>
</Page>
```

Code for toggle button:

```
private void Edit_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RightFrame.Navigate(typeof(SubPage1));
}

private void Edit_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RightFrame.Navigate(typeof(SubPage2));
}
```

So basically the toggle button switches the splitview content. The SubPages are just blank pages. The problem is that app crashes when navigation occurs.
I've noticed when I put this before invoking navigation:

```
RightFrame.Content = null;
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Then everything works fine. So I need to clear frame content and wait for it to finish I guess. But I think it should be done automatically. Could some one explain what am I doing wrong here and how it should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your code in `SubPage1` and `SubPage2` which might be creating the crashes, you can clear the resources when the page gets unloaded.

Alternatively, you can try below code:

```
private void Edit_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   RightFrame.Content = new SubPage1();
}

private void Edit_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   RightFrame.Content = new SubPage2();
}
```